# input: Disable letters only

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I disable letters in a input but still allows user to type symbols like **+** or **( )** and also **add space**?

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brunodd/5mk99r50/)**

```
$(".phone").on("keypress keyup blur",function (e) {    
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/, ""));
        if ((e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
            e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(".phone").on("keypress keyup blur", function (event) {
  switch (event.keyCode) {
    case 43: // + character
    case 40: // the ( character
    case 41: // the ) character
      break;
    default:
      const regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9.,/ $@()]+$");
      const key = event.key;
      if (!regex.test(key)) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
      }
      break;
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. However it's accepting characters like á or é for example. Nearly there.

Comment: Well, it may. I'g suggest you check the ASCII table, and add them as cases, this is first solution that comes in my mind. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using jquery.alphanum plugin which is very handy by the way.

[alphanum plugin](https://github.com/KevinSheedy/jquery.alphanum)

```
$('#phone').alphanum({
   allowLatin : false,
   allowOtherCharSets : false,
   allow : '+, (, )',    // Allow extra characters
});
```